# Replace value based on row number in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame looking kind of like this:

```
id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
x <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(id, x)
```

I want to keep only the first value that = 1 for each id, otherwise I want it to = 0, looking like this:

```
     id     x
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     1     0
3     1     0
4     2     0
5     2     1
6     2     0
7     3     1
8     3     0
9     3     0
```

I've tried this code, but with no luck:

````
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(x = if (any(x == 1)) replace(x,
                                      row_number() != 1, 0) else x)
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `replace` you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(y = replace(x, -match(1L, x), 0L))
#OR
#mutate(y = replace(x, which.max(x), 0L))

#     id     x     y
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     1
#2     1     1     0
#3     1     0     0
#4     2     0     0
#5     2     1     1
#6     2     1     0
#7     3     1     1
#8     3     1     0
#9     3     1     0
```

Comment: Thank you! That's the sort of solution that I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If `x` is binary, you can do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(x = +(which.max(x) == row_number()))

# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   id [3]
     id     x
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     1
2     1     0
3     1     0
4     2     0
5     2     1
6     2     0
7     3     1
8     3     0
9     3     0
```

If there are groups of `x` that don't contain a `1` you will need an extra condition:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(x = +(x == 1 & which.max(x) == row_number()))
```

Answer (score 3):

In *base* you can use `ave` to group by `id` and use `ifelse` with `cumsum` to replace after the first 1 with 0.

```
df$x <- ave(df$x, df$id, FUN=function(x) ifelse(cumsum(x)>1,0,x))
#df$x <- ifelse(ave(df$x, df$id, FUN=cumsum)>1, 0, df$x) #Alternativ
#df$x <- with(df, ifelse(ave(x, id, FUN=cumsum)>1, 0, x)) #Alternativ
df
#  id x
#1  1 1
#2  1 0
#3  1 0
#4  2 0
#5  2 1
#6  2 0
#7  3 1
#8  3 0
#9  3 0
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, x := replace(rep(0L, .N), match(1L, x), 1L), id]
```

Answer (score 0):

One `dplyr` solution could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(x = +(x == 1 & !duplicated(x)))

     id     x
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     1
2     1     0
3     1     0
4     2     0
5     2     1
6     2     0
7     3     1
8     3     0
9     3     0
```